# Can't install expo-cli

Tags: react-native, ubuntu, npm, expo

im trying to install expo-cli for react native project on ubuntu using npm  i tried npm install -g expo-cli but it doesn't work for me always the same error :npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

First try to clear cache:

```
npm cache verify
```

then,

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

OR

Add expo through yarn instead of npm,

```
npm install -g yarn
```

then,

```
yarn global add expo-cli
```

and you are good to go.